# Future simple or continuous?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, future

Which of the following is correct to say?

> 1. "House prices will be rising as soon as the economic crisis is over"
> 2. "House prices will rise as soon as the economic crisis is over"

Likewise

> 3. "people will go to the shops less often in the future as internet shopping becomes more popular"
> 4. "People will be going to the shops less often in the future as internet shopping becomes more popular"

I would use in both the future simple, but couldn't tell why the continuous tense is incorrect. Perhaps it isn't?

Comment: In the first example, you're using a continuous tense to describe a discontinuous event: when the house prices start rising.

Answer (score -1):

I feel you can use both to convey whether you think an immediate effect will occur later, or if the effect is merely going to begin in the future. They don't exactly mean the same thing, so I doubt one is more correct than the other.